# Graph theory 2-connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

So I have to prove that a 2-vertex-connected graph is also a 2-edge-connected graph,  any ideas becuase I cant even start the proof.

Comment: What is a "2-vertex-connected graph"? What is a "2-edge-connected graph"? Give some more background.

Comment: In graph theory a 2 vertex connected graph is a graph that becomes disconnected if we remove at least two vertices, same rule applies to the 2 edge connecetd graph.I hope I helped you .

Comment: the edge connectivity is always larger than or equal to the edge connectivity. Except for some trivial cases I can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that it's not 2-edge-connected. So it must have a cut edge. An endpoint of this edge is a cut vertex, a contradiction to the fact that the graph is 2-vertex-connected.

Comment: This proof is for 1-vertex connected and 1-edge connected. But a simple modification will make it work for the 2-version.

Comment: No, actually it says that if it is not 2-edge-connected (i.e. it has a edge cut of size one) then it will have a vertex cut of size one, so it couldn't be 2-vertex-connected.

Comment: When you remove a vertex, what happens to the edges that were connected to it?

Comment: When you remove a vertex of a graph you must remove the vertex and all the edges incident to it. (This is why in this case removing that vertex disconnects the graph.)